# "edit tags" does not auto focus the tags field

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-tag-editor, focus

As a 10k user, I can edit tags only:

> [image]

However, after clicking it, the tags field does not get auto  focus like it used to do before. I start typing and.... nothing happens. I need to focus the field manually.

This happens only on the initial page load, i.e. if I cancel then click "edit tags" again, the field does get auto focus.

Can this please be fixed? (As I said, I'm sure it worked before as I'm used to start typing right away.)

Browser: Chrome latest (53), Windows 7.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] - Chrome latest, Windows 10 (oh - I have to relaunch - will test again with that).

Comment: Strange. This happens on the *first* time "edit tags" is clicked on. If you cancel and click it again, the input gets focus.

Comment: @Oded true, I mentioned this in the report. (Now tried to make it more clear :))

Comment: Details, details :P

Comment: @Oded might be also due to the jQuery upgrade, no?

Comment: Could be related, though IIRC, the inline tag editor had some other work done on it recently (might have been fallout from the upgrade - need to check).

Comment: @Oded thanks, happy checking! :)

Comment: Yep, noticed this too. Not only on Chrome, same on Firefox and Safari (too lazy to check versions)

Comment: @Cai you mean on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/? Or do you see "edit tags" here as well? (Thought it's for 10k only, might be wrong though) Anyway thanks! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard only on GD, it is 10k only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

Not sure what changed (beyond Chrome itself), not sure if the jQuery update had anything to do with it, but I figured a fix that has worked in my local testing.

It is not 100% proof, but should happen very rarely now, if ever.

Comment: Thanks, fix confirmed.

Comment: If I upvote (probably also downvote, didn't try just yet) an answer then click the "edit tags", there is still no auto focus. Pretty minor and edge case, but if it's simple to fix, it would be great. :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried disabling my Chrome extensions to make sure they didn't interfere.

Comment: Why hasn't this been working for months on SO and MSO?

Comment: Who knows, @j08691? I certainly don't, having not worked there since late 2017. If you believe there's a bug, you should start a new question.