# Why doesn't the "edit tags" link auto-focus the tags field anymore?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, inline-tag-editor, focus

A few months ago the "edit tags" link on SO and Meta SO stopped focusing the tag field when clicking the link. Was this an intentional change, or a bug that's been ignored? If intentional, why?

Related:

- ["edit tags" does not auto focus the tags field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285413/edit-tags-does-not-auto-focus-the-tags-field/)
- ["Edit tags" link no longer focusing in tag editor area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409081/edit-tags-link-no-longer-focusing-in-tag-editor-area)

Comment: Do you know if this happens on any other sites, or is it just SO and MSO?

Comment: I've reproduced this here, on Meta SE, but it operates correctly on a Stack Overflow Team I'm in.

Comment: Reproduced on MSE and on SO; oddly, it worked *once* out of many attempts (Chrome on Android). Teams correctly focuses, but has... Other issues: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvrtn.png

Comment: @Shog9 If it randomly works once, then it sounds like some sort of race condition issue, e.g. where a `focus` event is dispatched but the element that is supposed to receive focus isn’t quite finished loading yet.

Comment: Entirely plausible, @Sebastian. The field is loaded asynchronously; it could be that network timing or even render time thwarts the effort to set focus.

Comment: I've just noticed this bug over on 3D Printing, using Chrome 122.0.6261.112. If you have RSI then every unnecessary click is annoying (to say the least).